# Ubuntu 12.04 transmission-daemon and zfsonlinux: bad file descriptor and corrupt pieces

Tags: 12.04, transmission, zfs

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with zfsonlinux and transmission-daemon.

The issues:

> sporadic Bad File Descriptor and Piece #xxx is corrupt errors.

After I recheck the torrent, everything seems fine. That happens only when downloading: once it's in seeding mode. This only happens after the torrent client has been running for some time.

I installed zfsonlinux from the [official stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable). I previously tried running transmission-daemon from the Ubuntu repository, but since I've switched to building the latest transmission from source with the latest libevent (all stable) - same thing.

I've seen [bug reports](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/4147) for that issue, but none of them seem to have a solution.

How can I fix these errors or at least understand where they come from and what I can do to rectify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out transmission-daemon has a bug, after verify it can show a torrent as 100%, but still fail when trying to read it. What makes the issue worse is that it reports Bad file descriptor on downloading torrents, not the bad one. After strace-ing it, I figured I always got bad file descriptor on the same file, no matter what it reported, so I removed that torrent and everything works fine. There's more information on the transmission [trac page](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/4147).